# Alias to a join query

Tags: sql, dml

```
( SELECT Vraboteni.v, Ulogi.p, Zarabotuva.honorar 
  FROM Vraboteni, Ulogi, Zarabotuva 
  WHERE Vraboteni.v = Ulogi.v 
    AND ima_uloga='sporedna' 
    AND Ulogi.p = Zarabotuva.p
) as F
JOIN
(  SELECT Vraboteni.v, Ulogi.p, Zarabotuva.honorar 
   FROM Vraboteni, Ulogi, Zarabotuva 
   WHERE Vraboteni.v = Ulogi.v 
     AND ima_uloga='glavna' 
     AND Ulogi.p = Zarabotuva.p
) as S
ON (F.honorar > S.honorar)
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the syntax that I am using above? I'm having the same issue over multiple queries and I'm not sure I quite understand how I am supposed to assign an alias when I use a join (having the same issue when trying to assign alliases to multiple nested joins)

Comment: Please edit your question and add sample data from your tables and your expected output. I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do here...

Comment: well, for starters, you are missing the top `SELECT`. Also, try to always use explicit joins instead of the old implicit ones

Comment: @krokodilko that's completely false. There's no issue with using `AS f` to give an alias to a table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subselects you join should be considered as a normal table or view, so imagine they are, and your select statement looks like this:

```
SELECT1 as F
JOIN SELECT2 as S ON (F.honorar > S.honorar)
```

This statement is missing essential parts, like a SELECT and FROM clause.

So fix it, if you want to join two selects, you should encapsulate them in another select, so you get:

```
SELECT
  S.*,
  F.*
FROM
  (SELECT ... ) AS F
  JOIN (SELECT ...) AS S ON (F.honorar > S.honorar)
```

Alternatively, you could get rid of the two subselects, use normal joins for all your tables, and end up with a query like this:

```
SELECT 
  Vraboteni.v, Ulogi.p, Zarabotuva.honorar 
FROM 
  Vraboteni AS v1
    JOIN Ulogi AS u1 ON v1.v = u1.v
    JOIN Zarabotuva AS z1 ON u1.p = z1.p
  CROSS JOIN Vraboteni AS v2 -- Not sure if you would want/need a condition here
    JOIN Ulogi AS u2 ON v2.v = u2.v
    JOIN Zarabotuva AS z2 ON u2.p = z2.p
WHERE 
  v1.ima_uloga = 'sporedna' -- Not sure if this should be v1, u1 or z1
  AND v2.ima_uloga = 'glavna'
  AND z1.honorar > z2.honorar
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what you need to do:

```
SELECT     *
FROM
         (SELECT Vraboteni.v
              , Ulogi.p
              , Zarabotuva.honorar
          FROM   Vraboteni
              , Ulogi
              , Zarabotuva
          WHERE  Vraboteni.v = Ulogi.v
                AND ima_uloga = 'sporedna'
                AND Ulogi.p = Zarabotuva.p) AS F
         JOIN
            (SELECT Vraboteni.v
                 , Ulogi.p
                 , Zarabotuva.honorar
             FROM   Vraboteni
                 , Ulogi
                 , Zarabotuva
             WHERE  Vraboteni.v = Ulogi.v
                   AND ima_uloga = 'glavna'
                   AND Ulogi.p = Zarabotuva.p) AS S ON F.honorar > S.honorar;
```